# HTML Objects/SVG swap on browser back

Tags: html, object, svg

When using the back button to my index page, my logo svg and svg animation switch places. This causes the logo to show up in the place of the background animation.

It only seems to be happening in Chrome. Should be replicated by clicking on one of the links in my 'work' section, then by using the browsers back button.

http://emmersonic.com

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm the bug.  The entire DOM structure for the embedded `<object>` is showing up in the incorrect spot in the main page DOM.  I can't see anything obvious in the main page scripts that should be messing with the embedded objects, either.  After much searching (complicated by the fact that "object" isn't a terribly informative search term) I can't find an existing issue report on [Chromium issues](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list), so I suggest you start one.

Comment: Seems to be reported as a bug in Chrome here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=352762

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully the issue will be resolved soon.