# SVG loaded via objects all jumbled up

Tags: image, browser, svg, responsive-design, loading

So this is an interesting one. I did a test of using the [clown car technique](http://www.standardista.com/responsive-images-clown-car-technique/) for showing responsive images via svgs loaded via an object tag because I really like the approach.

Now this works all fine, except when you have a few of them on one page with the cache normally activated, you leave the site to go to anywhere else in the interwebs and then press the back button - suddenly all images are mixed up, even though the code is still correct, ie:

object 1 loads svg that shows image from object 3
object 3 loads svg that shows image from object 5
etc.

Totally random and I just can't explain how this can happen. And it only ever happens when I go back to the page via the back command of the browser (chrome).

Has anyone experienced anything like this before??

I guess I'll stick to good old normal images for now...

Comment: Another question based on the same bug:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203572/html-objects-svg-swap-on-browser-back

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same bug. And [so did Google](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=350893)!

I suppose we'll have to use inline SVGs as loading through `<img>` tags aren't a possibility for me.

If you only have a single page app, you could add `target="_blank"` to your `<a>` tags to ensure the back button will come into play far less.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this, I already though I'm going mad here...I guess really clever svgs are still not an alternative just yet.